# Disable select option if already selected in another select box( as have infinity select box) so cant give it ID

Tags: jquery-select2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31osi.png)
i have multiple select option and i need to make if i select from first option an item so it disable or diapered from hull selected option while i cant give the select option an id as it is generated from plus icon

i have multiple select option and i need to make if i select from first option an item so it disable or diapered from hull selected option while i cant give the select option an id as it is generated from plus icon